# How to get result of hadoop hdfs command to check cluster status

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

For the below command, it produces information such as replication status, cluster health status, number of blocks, datanodes, etc...

```
./hadoop-2.5.1/bin/hdfs fsck /
```

In the same way, the below command gives the output of how much space has been occupied in Hadoop

```
./hadoop-2.5.1/bin/hdfs dfs -df -h
Filesystem                        Size    Used  Available  Use%
hdfs://HadoopCluster             100.4 T  84.6 T     15.8 T   84%
```

I can able to get information either dfshealth.html or login system and execute the command.

Is there way to get information via Java API?

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, all of this is exposed through API that can be accessed via Java. I think the class you are looking for is HdfsAdmin (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/client/HdfsAdmin.html).

Comment: I'm using Hadoop 2 and in that HDFSAdmin is not present

Answer (score 0):

All the CLI commands map to Java classes

`hdfs dfs` runs `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell`

https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.5.1/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/bin/hdfs#L146

In response to your other comment, I think you're looking for DFSAdmin, which has a report method

https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.5.1/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/tools/DFSAdmin.java